# Ambiguous grammar (using Bison)

Tags: grammar, bison, lalr

I've got a problem with an ambiguous grammar. I've got this:

```
%token identifier
%token lolcakes

%start program

%%

program
    : call_or_definitions;

expression
    : identifier
    | lolcakes;

expressions
    : expression
    | expressions ',' expression;

call_or_definition
    : function_call
    | function_definition;

call_or_definitions
    : call_or_definition
    | call_or_definitions call_or_definition;

function_argument_core
    : identifier
    | identifier '=' expression
    | identifier '=' '{' expressions '}';

function_call
    : expression '(' function_arguments ')' ';';

function_definition
    : identifier '(' function_definition_arguments ')' '{' '}';

function_argument
    : lolcakes
    | function_argument_core;

function_arguments
    : function_argument 
    | function_arguments ',' function_argument

function_definition_argument
    : expression function_argument_core
    | function_argument_core;

function_definition_arguments
    : function_definition_argument
    | function_definition_arguments ',' function_definition_argument;
```

It's a subset of my genuine grammar which is separately compilable. At the moment, it generates an S/R conflict between `function_call` and `function_definition` when encountering the stream `identifier (`. I'm trying to convince Bison that it doesn't need to make the decision until later in the token stream by unifying the grammar for function calls and function definitions. In other words, if it encounters something that's common to both calls and definitions, it can reduce that without needing to know which is which, and if it encounters something else, that something else would clearly label which is which. Is that even possible, and if so, how can I do it? I'd really rather avoid having to alter the structure of the input stream if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem should not arise until you see `identifier ( identifier` with a lookahead of `,` or `)`. At that point the parser has to decide whether to reduce the *second* identifier as a `function_definition_argument` or an `expression` (to become `function_argument`).

You *can* solve this purely in the grammar by brute force, but it will lead you into a maze of nonterminals like `expression_not_naked_identifier` and `ambiguous_begining_of_function_defn_or_call`, with resulting rampant duplication of semantic actions.

It would probably be more maintainable (and lead to more intelligible syntax error messages) to write something like

```
definition_or_call_start: identifier '(' generic_argument_list ')'
generic_argument_list: generic_argument
                     | generic_argument_list ',' generic_argument
generic_argument: expression 
                | function_argument_core
                | ...
function_call: definition_or_call_start ';';
function_definition : definition_or_call_start '{' '}';
```

and then check as a semantic constraint in the action for the last two productions that the actual `generic_arguments` you have parsed match the use they're being put to.

Comment: I didn't have a problem using this approach to reduce ambiguity at all. The only thing I have yet to do is define expression_not_identifier in my non-trivial grammar, which could be ... fun ... but I think that apart from that, this is a quite managable solution in this case.

Comment: OK, you might have been right. Just listing everything this way is, well, not exactly DRY-friendly and I'd have to duplicate my whole expression tree to implement expression_not_identifier

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an `expression` can consist of a single `identifier`. At this time the parser needs to decide whether it's a `identifier` only or if it shall reduce it to `expression`, since that will decide on the path afterwards.